# Perl - multiple matches on same line with alternation

Tags: regex, perl, multiple-matches

I need to extract multiple matches for a string on a single line.  The line looks something like this:

**./staticRoutes.10.10.30_VC;./staticRoutes.10.10.40_FEEDS**

I need to extract each filename and put it in some @array.  The file name on the line is separated by a **;**.  So in the above example, i want to extract just **staticRoutes.10.10.30_VC** and **staticRoutes.10.10.40_FEEDS**

Any help greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the regex version, it would not contain the leading `./` in the result. If this is worth it, you can use this, otherwise I would prefer the split solution.

```
my $s = "./staticRoutes.10.10.30_VC;./staticRoutes.10.10.40_FEEDS";
my @res = $s =~ m~[^/]+(?=;|$)~g;
```

This would match any character that is not a `/` (the `[^/]+` part), before a `;` or the end of the string (the `(?=;|$)` part)

Comment: Note that this will only work if the fields always have a `/` in them. Add a `;` in the negated character class if you want to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

```
my $some_string = './staticRoutes.10.10.30_VC;./staticRoutes.10.10.40_FEEDS';
my @array = split /;/, $some_string;
```

Comment: Firstly, many thanks for your reply. I need to strip out the ./ from each match.  Now I know i could do that using a substitute/replace on another line of code but is it possible to make the match so that I dont need to do that..?